# Determine the nature of this series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I determine if this series converges ? $\overset{\infty}{\sum}\frac{\ln n!}{n^3}$. Cauchy and d'Alembert have proved inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** $$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(k) \leq n \ln(n)$$

Comment: Okkkay yes thank you very much; I'd done that already but had failed to notice that the series associated to $\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ converges